# Git just partly adds huge binary files

Tags: git, version-control

I wanted to use Git for data storage, which will be used by automatic tools (so speed is not as important). But when ever I try to add to git a huge binary file (in my case it is a zip file with size of 24.2GB), it does it just partly.

**My process:**

1. Prepare folder with 2 huge binary files just for test;
2. Call `git init` to initialize git project;
3. `git add -A -v -f` to add all the files to stage (log shows, that both files are added, no errors nor warnings);
4. Checked .git folder, its size is just 41.6 MB, which seemed too small, but let's continue;
5. `git commit -m "initial commit"` to make a commit (log shows 2 files changed, size of .git folder is still 41.6 MB);
6. Deleted one of media;
7. `git reset --hard HEAD` - got back only 222 MB of binary file.

Git version: 2.13.2.windows.1

System: Windows Server 2016 Standard x64

Git has all default configuration

What might be the problem and is it somehow possible to fix it without switching to git LFS or other version controll system?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use git for that?

Comment: Version control (this is just one of cases, later there will also be text files, which must show the changes, but in that case there shouldn't be such a big files, but who knows, I won't be the final user)

Comment: Git LFS is not an option right now

Comment: Git is not designed to mange binary files, that's what LFS is for. For multi-gigabyte files it's even less of a good idea. If LFS isn't an option, it may be a better idea to utilize another storage system for this, like AWS S3 or an FTP server. Also, try using `git count-objects -H -v` to see the actual size of objects being managed by the repository.

Comment: @Derek - anyway, it would be very interesting to know why exactly is Git behaving like that. I mean - file is just bytes; why should Git suddenly truncate it? Is there some hard-coded limit in Git? In that case it would be good to know. I'd even say - it should be stressed in large red letters somewhere in user's manual: "Git will corrupt your files if size exceeds X !"

Comment: @JustAMartin That would really be nice to know. Because now from the user's point, git does what told, but history gets corrupted

Comment: @kaplis What's the type of the binary files did you used? I have both `.docx` and `.zip`, the size of .git doesn't changed after executing `git reset --hard HEAD`. And it also make sense, since the working tree is clean and the `HEAD` is not changed neither.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT As I wrote in the description, I used .zip files. But I think, that the problem is not in the extension, but in the size of those files

Comment: If some objects are packed in `.git/objects/pack`, the `.git` folder size may be small. So can you show the output of the command `find .git/objects -type f`, and check if the output contains `git/objects/pack/*.pack`?

Comment: Heh, I updated git to the latest version and tried on new project. `After git add -A` I got an error `fatal: Cannot handle files this big`, so, I suppose I will close the question. As far as I understand, that really was Git bug, which in the lates version at least is somehow handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to use Git for data storage, which will be used by automatic tools (so speed is not as important).

Whether speed is important or not, Git is not a database or a general purpose filesystem and trying to use it like one generally leaves everyone disappointed.  This is a good example, where you've tried to do something perfectly reasonable in a general purpose filesystem, which is something that is obviously broken in your build of Git.

Dealing with extremely large files is a series of rather brittle operations that regresses easily and often goes unnoticed because nobody checks in multi-gigabyte files because it's bad at handling them.

I can't guess what other problems you'll discover but I suspect there will be some.  (Especially if you try to push this to a hosting provider.)

You haven't asked a question in your question, it reads more like a bug report.  Indeed that's what it is - this is an unexpected bug - and you should report it on the Git for Windows issue tracker.

Comment: I updated my question and added a real question to that.
But is it actually possible to somehow avoid this problem, because switching to other vcs is too expensive right now

Comment: With help of colleague I found an [unresolved Github issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1063). Looks like you where rights and it is really a Git for windows bug